# State-of-the-art of Java RMI compression

Tags: java, rmi

If found this [Java World article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077363/soa/compress-your-data.html) about RMI compression. To implement the compression it suggests to implement a `RMIClientSocketFactory` and a `RMIServerSocketFactory`, which seems nice and easy.

Although the article is from 2002 and therefore I am wondering if this is still the State-of-the-art approach.

Comment: AFAIK RMI itself is no longer considered 'stage of the art'... all companies I worked for in the last years were exposing JSON (over HTTP and/or rabbitmq) rather than RMI.  Of course this is a general statement and there could be exceptions depending on your specific requirements, infrastructure etc.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It does not matter if your statement is general. My question is also general.

Comment: LOL you have a point :)

Comment: It is still the correct approach. RMI hasn't changed significantly since 1.5.

Comment: So, no, it's not state-of-the-art anymore. (An) Upside of REST is that it's more loosely coupled, without compromising

Comment: @Danielson and everybody else It is still the state-of-the-art way *to do what is asked in the question.*